# XCode4 couldn't resolve local server

Tags: git, xcode4, dns, lan

I tried to deploy git server on my internal network server (LAN). I've successfully installed gitosis and played around with it (push, pull, clone etc) using Terminal. But, the weirdness is come when I started to use XCode4. It didn't resolve the IP address

but it work fine for any random domain in the net, e.g. google.com

My guess was: the problem might be related to nameserver. Then, I deployed a DNS server in my local network and put name on it. I deployed a bind9 DNS server on my Ubuntu and register dycodenux.com as domain and git.dycodenux.com as the server name. I can then resolve it very quickly from my terminal (I can ping and dig it). Then, I tried it on XCode4: and it again unreachable.

Please help me with some ideas that might be DEFINITELY wrong. Thanks!

Comment: Here's the screenshot: http://cl.ly/0s1Q3c3S2a0o1e2k3t03

Answer (score 0):

I think it is looking for an address more like git.dycodenux.com/project.git try that